# Setting the width of an inner modal nested within an outer modal

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have 2 modals nested within eachother, and I want to control the width of the inner modal. How do I do that?

The outer modal is launched from a quick action. The user can take some action from the outer modal that creates the inner modal. The inner modal takes the width of the outer modal. Instead, I want to control that width, but I can't seem to access that html to apply the css. How do I do this?

When inspecting the inner modal, this css does the trick. but I can't access the outer container from c:nestedModal. 
      .slds-modal__container{
          width:90%;
          max-width: none;
          min-width: 40rem;
          height: 100%;
          padding: 3rem 0;
      }

The outer modal contains several components. Here is the code from the sub-component that creates the inner modal.

```
$A.createComponent(
      "c:nestedModal",
      { dataWrapper: wrap},
      function(content, status) {
        if (status == "SUCCESS") {
          component.find("overLib").showCustomModal({
            body: content,
            showCloseButton: true,
            closeCallback: function() {

            }
          });
        }
      }
    );
  },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [lightning:overlayLibrary](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:overlayLibrary/documentation) inherits styling from [slds-modal](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/modals/), you could use standard modal styling in overlaylibrary's `cssClass` attribute to specify the width.

Before writing custom styling, try standard modal options as `.slds-modal_small`, `.slds-modal_medium` or `.slds-modal_large` to see if it fits your requirement.

```
component.find('overLib').showCustomModal({
    cssClass: "mymodal slds-modal_small",
    // set other properties
})
```

Comment: using the standard modal option did the trick `cssClass: "mymodal slds-modal_small" `
How did you know mymodal is the property that needed to be set?

Comment: `mymodal` is just a css class name from documentation's example I copied. `slds-modal_small` is the slds class responsible for making it work.

Comment: this helped me too, thank you!